# javascript doesn't fire using Clientscript.RegisterStartupScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

It should be simple, but I didn't figure out why the javascript function didn't execute. in my code, I check something. If it is fit the condition then I call the javascript function. Would some one tell me how to fix it. Thanks.

This is code on my code behind:

```
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "confirm", "confirmOrder();", True)
```

There is my javasscript:

```
 function confirmOrder() {
            alert('test confrim');
            var ans=confirm('This is order correct?')
            document.getElementById('hdOrderConfirm').value = ans;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "confirm", "confirmOrder();", true);
```

When you are using an `UpdatePanel` you cannot use your `JavaScript` function as you have did. You have to use `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`.`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` method used to add client script to a page when the control is wrapped inside an `UpdatePanel`.

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.

Comment: @afnanahmad, it works. Would you explanation what is wrong my code. Thanks.